# Monkeypatching hardcoded global configuration loaded from a .py file

Tags: python, python-2.7

A co-worker has a library that uses a hard-coded configuration defined in its own file. For instance:

constants.py:

```
API_URL="http://example.com/bogus"
```

Throughout the rest of the library, the configuration is accessed in the following manner.

```
from constants import API_URL
```

As you can imagine, this is not very flexible and causes problems during testing. If I want to change the configuration, I have to modify constants.py, which is in source code management.

Naturally, I'd much rather load the configuration from a JSON or YAML file. I can read the configuration into an object with no problems. Is there a way I can override the `constants.py` module without breaking the code, so that each global, e.g. `API_URL` is replaced by a value provided by my file?

I was thinking that after each `from constants import ...` I could add something like this:

```
from constants import *  # existing configuration import
import json
new_config = json.load(open('config.json'))  # load my config file into a dictionary
constants.__dict__.update(new_config)        # override any constants with what I've loaded
```

The problem with this, of course, is that it's not very "DRY" and looks like it might be brittle.

Does anyone have a suggestion for doing this more cleanly? Thanks!

EDIT: looks like my approach doesn't work anyway. I guess "from  import *" copies the values from the module into the current module's global scope?

DOUBLE EDIT: no, it does work; I'm just confused. But rather than doing this in X different files I'd like to have it work transparently if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @MartijnPieters. I ended up using your suggestion.

Comment: Well, in that case, I've typed that up as an actual answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from module import <name>` creates a reference in the importing module global namespace to the imported object. If that is an immutable, that means you now have to monkeypatch the value in the module that imported it.

Your only hope is to be the first to import constants and monkeypatch the names in that module. Subsequent imports will then use your monkeypatched values.

To patch the original module early, the following is enough:

```
import constants

for name, value in new_config.iteritems():
    setattr(constants, name, value)
```